# jQuery: Define multiple variables with a single chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to define multiple variables with a single jQuery chain?

```
var sectionTable = jQuery("#sectionsTable");
var sectionTableRows = sectionTable.find("tr");
var sectionTableColumns = sectionTableRows.find("td");
```

I don't know what the syntax would be if it is possible but if you took the 3 variables above how could you chain them and would it be considered good practice?

Many thanks

Chris

EDIT: Wow, thanks for all the comments. Sorry for being vague, what I was after was a better way (if one exists) of defining child variables from a parent variable. That's why I thought of using the chain and wondered if a way existed. Thanks for the great advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to, anything is possible :

Of the top of my head, you could try to do something like this :

```
var sectionTable,
    sectionTableRows, 
    sectionTableColumns = $('td', (sectionTableRows = $('tr',(sectionTable = $('#sectionsTable')))));
```

Another ideea would be to build a mini-plugin that assigns the current jquery object to a certain field of an object :

```
jQuery.fn.assignTo = function(variableName,namespace){
    var ns = namespace || window;
    ns[variableName] = this;
    return this;
}
```

With this peace of code you could do the following :

```
var sections = {};
jQuery("#sectionsTable")
    .assignTo('sectionTable',sections)
    .find("tr")
        .assignTo('sectionTableRows',sections)
        .find("td")
            .assignTo('sectionTableColumns',sections);

console.log(sections.sectionTable);
console.log(sections.sectionTableRows);
console.log(sections.sectionTableColumns);
```

Of course, if you do not specify any namespace, the variables will be global (will be attached to the window object);

Any way, I do not encourage you to use these examples, because it doesn't make very much sense to worsen your code's readability in favour of fewer equal signs and `var` declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is basically what I meant, but I suppose what I was after were opinions on whether or not I was defining those 3 variables correctly or if there was a better way.

Comment: @Chris In that case, your way is very good. The code is readable and you define variables based on previous ones, thus making your code more efficient (it's like a sort of miniature caching).

Comment: Excellent thanks. I'm just learning and thought it an important thing to ask. Thanks to everyone for their advice.

Answer (score 5):

I maybe don't really understand what you want or need, but you can chain any function for a jQuery wrapped set and "end" it and therefor "go back" to the previous set. For instance:

```
jQuery("#sectionsTable").css('background-color', 'red')
.find('tr').css('background-color', 'yellow')
.find('td').css('background-color', 'black')
.end() // back to 'tr'
.doSomething()
.end() // back to '#sectionsTable'
.doSomething();
```

However, this would imply that you only need to access those elements **once**. If you need to access them later in your code, you **always** should store the results references in variables for several performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

You could rewrite it as follows:

```
var $sectionTable = $('#sectionsTable'),
    $sectionTableRows = $('tr', $sectionTable),
    $sectionTableColumns = $('td', $sectionTableRows);
```

But of course, that’s only useful if you’re actually gonna use all three of those variables.

Comment: Would this be a better way to the one I used as my example?

Comment: @Chris The only real difference (other than the “single” `var` declaration) is that this example uses less function calls (only three) because it avoids `.find()` and uses context instead. This makes it slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing comes to my mind is **one-var declaration**, like:

```
var sectionTable = jQuery("#sectionsTable"), 
sectionTableRows = sectionTable.find("tr"), 
sectionTableColumns = sectionTableRows.find("td");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?

What's wrong with defining the three variables?

(No, you can't).

---

If you didn't **need** the `sectionTable` or `sectionTableRows` variables *at all*, you could of course do;

```
var sectionTableColumns = jQuery("#sectionsTable").find("tr").find("td");
```

Which, using the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), could be shortened to just;

```
var sectionTableColumns = jQuery("#sectionsTable tr td");
```

Comment: It is possible, see @Mathias Bynens post

Comment: @steven.yang: That isn't a single chain, as asked for in the OP.

Comment: @steven I think the OP was quite unclear about what he means. This seems like a very useful answer to me, not worth a downvote. Mathias's answer is good as well, depending on the meaning of "chaining".

Comment: Just looking for the best way to define children from the parent.